# xcode : Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: xcode, cocoa, ffmpeg, codesign, appstore-sandbox

In a sandboxed mac app i am using static build of codesigned ffmpeg. The ffmpeg requires fonts.conf file. So i am doing this

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/fonts/"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fonts" ofType:@"conf"] toPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/fonts/fonts.conf"] error:NULL];

NSString *fontconfigFile= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/fonts/fonts.conf"];
NSString *fontconfigPath= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/fonts/"];

setenv("FONTCONFIG_FILE", [fontconfigFile UTF8String], 0);
setenv("FONTCONFIG_PATH", [fontconfigPath UTF8String], 0);
```

But when i do that ffmpeg fails to run. What am i doing wrong?
I want the mac app to run in 10.9 and 10.10.

The question is this how do i instruct xcode where to pick up the fonts.conf from my mac app when it runs?

Comment: What is the motivation to not use NSString and  stringByAppendingPathComponent? Or even NSURL?

Answer (score 0):

What is the motivation to not use NSString and  stringByAppendingPathComponent? Or even NSURL? Did you step with the debugger to see if the error is because the file is not copied or it's a problem with setenv?